# Prevent subdomain from redirecting to SSL/HTTPS in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a domain `https://secondubly.tv` setup with SSL that redirects to another website - this portion works perfectly fine. I also have a subdomain that I haven't setup with SSL - `bot.secondubly.tv` but every time I try to access it, I end getting redirected to `https://secondubly.tv` which in turn redirects me to another website. I imagine it's just ignoring the first block adn going to the block below it. I'm really struggling on how to get this working *without* SSL, and could use some help.

```
# Server that handles sending non-SSL traffic to SSL.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name bot.secondubly.tv www.bot.secondubly.tv;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:25000;
    }
}

server {
    server_name secondubly.tv www.secondubly.tv;
    return 301 https://twitch.tv/secondubly$request_uri;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate key; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key key; # managed by Certbot
    include ...nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam ...dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.secondubly.tv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = secondubly.tv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name secondubly.tv www.secondubly.tv;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I feel like I'm just not understanding something really basic here? Why is it skipping the proxy_pass section? The server names are there and they're accurate, so what gives?

Comment: Have you set an [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) with `includeSubDomains`?

Comment: I did not! I managed to actually get this solved - it looked like there was a caching issue in my browser that was causing the problem - it was auto-redirecting to the top level domain due to that - once I cleared the cache out my browser, everything worked as intended!